# Flutter. GridView inside Container

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'Login.dart';
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image:DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("images/black_background_logo.png"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CarouselDemo(),
          HomePanel()
        ],
      ),
    );

  }

}

List<String> images = [
  'https://skalka-app.ru/banners/1.png',
  'https://skalka-app.ru/banners/2.png',
  'https://skalka-app.ru/banners/3.png',
] ;
class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CarouselSlider(
    options: CarouselOptions(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
      viewportFraction: 1.0,
      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
      reverse: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 8),
      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    ),
    items: images.map((i) {
      return Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
              //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.amber
              ),
              child: Image.network(i,fit: BoxFit.cover, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,)
          );
        },
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}

class HomePanel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    List<String> data = <String>["Twitter", "Reddit", "YouTube", "Facebook",
      "Vimeo", "GitHub", "GitLab", "BitBucket", "LinkedIn", "Medium",
      "Tumblr", "Instagram", "Pinterest"];
    List<RaisedButton> myWidgets = data.map((item) {
      return new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(item),
          onPressed: () async {

          }
      );
    }).toList();
    GridView myGrid = GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: myWidgets
    );

    return Container(

      height: height*0.3,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.red,
      child:  myGrid
      );


  }
}
```

**I'm trying to add a GridView to a Container, but an indent appears at the top. Please tell me how to fix this?**

I painted the Container red to show that there is a padding on top. I could not find a solution to this problem on the Internet. I'm new to Flutter, maybe I missed an important point in building this widget.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Add padding of EdgeInsets.zero to remove any padding from Container.

Comment: From the code provided, it also seems like you are just hard setting the `height ` and `width` without needing things like `decoration`. I would suggest `SizedBox` if *absolute* sizing is the only purpose of the `Container` here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try wrap GridView with a MediaQuery.removePadding() then set removeTop property to True.

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: GridView(
     .......
    )
  );
```

Comment: This is what I need! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code pretty much, just for the `Carousel`, I have used the `ListView.builder()`. Rest is fine.

> The catch is to use [Expanded class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) inside your `Column()` to take the height automatically for the `Carousel`

Follow the code along, and see the result as well, no extra space in the UI in the `GridView`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> images = [
    'https://skalka-app.ru/banners/1.png',
    'https://skalka-app.ru/banners/2.png',
    'https://skalka-app.ru/banners/3.png',
  ];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Expanded used to take up the space
            Expanded(
              // ListView.builder, use your carousel here
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: images.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  // look at this as well, no height, only width
                  // given for the image
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: NetworkImage(images[index])
                      )
                    )
                  );
                }
              )
            ),
            HomePanel()
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


class HomePanel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    List<String> data = <String>["Twitter", "Reddit", "YouTube", "Facebook",
      "Vimeo", "GitHub", "GitLab", "BitBucket", "LinkedIn", "Medium",
      "Tumblr", "Instagram", "Pinterest"];
    List<RaisedButton> myWidgets = data.map((item) {
      return new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(item),
          onPressed: () async {

          }
      );
    }).toList();
    GridView myGrid = GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: myWidgets
    );

    return Container(
      height: height*0.3,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.red,
      child:  myGrid
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

Look at the design closely in the result, no extra spacing or padding

[image: Resultant image]